# Only one specific character missing when compiling with biber and xelatex

Tags: xetex, biber, unicode, listingsutf8

I'm having trouble showing proper reference list - one letter just does not appear. I googled possible solutions, and updated the fonts, packages, but still can't resolve this.

Here's MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Unicode in references
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Unicode in references
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chicago-authordate, autocite=inline,bibencoding=utf8, sorting=nyt, language=false, doi=false, url=false, isbn=false, hyperref=true, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=100, dashed=false, uniquelist=false, refsegment=chapter, defernumbers=true]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{mylibrary}
\begin{document}
The problem letter \u{g}.
\textcite{javorcik2011migrant}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The mylibrary file contains the following (the file is saved as utf-8 encoded file):

```
@article{javorcik2011migrant,
    Author = {Javorcik, Beata S and {\"O}zden, \c{C}a\u{g}lar and Spatareanu, Mariana and Neagu, Cristina},
    Date-Added = {2016-05-23 20:21:57 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-05-27 19:12:23 +0000},
    Doi = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jdeveco.2010.01.012},
    Issn = {0304-3878},
    Journal = {Journal of Development {E}conomics},
    Keywords = {Brain drain},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {231 - 241},
    Title = {Migrant networks and foreign direct investment},
    Volume = {94},
    Xurl = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304387810000222},
    Year = {2011},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jdeveco.2010.01.012}}
```

This is what I see in the compiled file:
[image: What I see in the output]

Note that the letter ğ is shown in the text no problem, but for some reason it does not appear in the reference list. This is the log output:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=xelatex 2016.5.27)  27 MAY 2016 22:06
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**/Users/removed/Dropbox/Thesis/currentdraft/temptexfiles/test.tex
(/Users/removed/Dropbox/Thesis/currentdraft/temptexfiles/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15


Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex_.sty
Package: biblatex_ 2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/A
B)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count87
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count88

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count89
\c@listtotal=\count90
\c@listcount=\count91
\c@liststart=\count92
\c@liststop=\count93
\c@citecount=\count94
\c@citetotal=\count95
\c@multicitecount=\count96
\c@multicitetotal=\count97
\c@instcount=\count98
\c@maxnames=\count99
\c@minnames=\count100
\c@maxitems=\count101
\c@minitems=\count102
\c@citecounter=\count103
\c@savedcitecounter=\count104
\c@uniquelist=\count105
\c@uniquename=\count106
\c@refsection=\count107
\c@refsegment=\count108
\c@maxextratitle=\count109
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count110
\c@maxextrayear=\count111
\c@maxextraalpha=\count112
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count113
\c@highnamepenalty=\count114
\c@lownamepenalty=\count115
\c@maxparens=\count116
\c@parenlevel=\count117
\blx@tempcnta=\count118
\blx@tempcntb=\count119
\blx@tempcntc=\count120
\blx@maxsection=\count121
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count122
\blx@notetype=\count123
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count124
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count125
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count126
\labelnumberwidth=\skip43
\labelalphawidth=\skip44
\biblabelsep=\skip45
\bibitemsep=\skip46
\bibnamesep=\skip47
\bibinitsep=\skip48
\bibparsep=\skip49
\bibhang=\skip50
\blx@bcfin=\read1
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\c@mincomprange=\count127
\c@maxcomprange=\count128
\c@mincompwidth=\count129
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'chicago-authordate.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count130
\c@savedafterword=\count131
\c@annotator=\count132
\c@savedannotator=\count133
\c@author=\count134
\c@savedauthor=\count135
\c@bookauthor=\count136
\c@savedbookauthor=\count137
\c@commentator=\count138
\c@savedcommentator=\count139
\c@editor=\count140
\c@savededitor=\count141
\c@editora=\count142
\c@savededitora=\count143
\c@editorb=\count144
\c@savededitorb=\count145
\c@editorc=\count146
\c@savededitorc=\count147
\c@foreword=\count148
\c@savedforeword=\count149
\c@holder=\count150
\c@savedholder=\count151
\c@introduction=\count152
\c@savedintroduction=\count153
\c@namea=\count154
\c@savednamea=\count155
\c@nameb=\count156
\c@savednameb=\count157
\c@namec=\count158
\c@savednamec=\count159
\c@translator=\count160
\c@savedtranslator=\count161
\c@shortauthor=\count162
\c@savedshortauthor=\count163
\c@shorteditor=\count164
\c@savedshorteditor=\count165
\c@labelname=\count166
\c@savedlabelname=\count167
\c@institution=\count168
\c@savedinstitution=\count169
\c@lista=\count170
\c@savedlista=\count171
\c@listb=\count172
\c@savedlistb=\count173
\c@listc=\count174
\c@savedlistc=\count175
\c@listd=\count176
\c@savedlistd=\count177
\c@liste=\count178
\c@savedliste=\count179
\c@listf=\count180
\c@savedlistf=\count181
\c@location=\count182
\c@savedlocation=\count183
\c@organization=\count184
\c@savedorganization=\count185
\c@origlocation=\count186
\c@savedoriglocation=\count187
\c@origpublisher=\count188
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count189
\c@publisher=\count190
\c@savedpublisher=\count191
\c@language=\count192
\c@savedlanguage=\count193
\c@pageref=\count194
\c@savedpageref=\count195
\shorthandwidth=\skip51
\shortjournalwidth=\skip52
\shortserieswidth=\skip53
\shorttitlewidth=\skip54
\shortauthorwidth=\skip55
\shorteditorwidth=\skip56
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex_.def' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex_.def
File: biblatex_.def 
\c@textcitecount=\count196
\c@textcitetotal=\count197
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count198
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count199
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count266
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count267
\c@smartand=\count268
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'chicago-authordate'..
.
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'chicago-authordate.bbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-authorda
te.bbx
File: chicago-authordate.bbx 2016/03/21 v 2.9a biblatex bibliography style
\lositemsep=\skip57
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'chicago-authordate'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'chicago-authordate.cbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-authorda
te.cbx
File: chicago-authordate.cbx 2016/03/18 v 2.9a biblatex citation style
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetexts'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
)

! Package biblatex Error: Language 'false' not supported.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11475 \blx@processoptions

Failed to find a matching 'false.lbx' file.


! Package keyval Error: dashed undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11475 \blx@processoptions

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
)

Package biblatex Warning: Missing 'hyperref' package.
(biblatex)                Setting hyperref=false.

\@quotelevel=\count269
\@quotereset=\count270

! Package biblatex Error: \chapter not provided by class.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \begin{document}

The document class does not seems to support chapters.

(/Users/removed/Dropbox/Thesis/currentdraft/temptexfiles/test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
Package biblatex Info: XeTeX detected.
(biblatex)             Assuming input encoding 'utf8'.
Package biblatex Info: Data encoding 'utf8' specified.
(biblatex)             No need to reencode data.
\openout3 = `test.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'test.bbl' found.

(/Users/removed/Dropbox/Thesis/currentdraft/temptexfiles/test.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 6.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 6.
Missing character: There is no ğ in font ecrm1200!

[1

] (/Users/removed/Dropbox/Thesis/currentdraft/temptexfiles/test.aux)
Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'test.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `test.run.xml'.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 6710 strings out of 493632
 118771 string characters out of 6144722
 555720 words of memory out of 5000000
 10109 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 6931 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 44i,4n,43p,911b,930s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on /Users/removed/Dropbox/Thesis/currentdraft/temptexfil
es/test.pdf (1 page).
```

This is the contents of the .blg file:

```
[0] Config.pm:340> INFO - This is Biber 2.4
[0] Config.pm:343> INFO - Logfile is '/Users/removed/Dropbox/Thesis/currentdraft/temptexfiles/test.blg'
[44] biber-darwin:287> INFO - === Fri May 27, 2016, 22:06:51
[59] Biber.pm:347> INFO - Reading '/Users/removed/Dropbox/Thesis/currentdraft/temptexfiles/test.bcf'
[153] Biber.pm:741> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[163] Biber.pm:3150> INFO - Processing section 0
[202] Biber.pm:3307> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'mylibrary.bib' for section 0
[380] bibtex.pm:1124> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[487] bibtex.pm:985> INFO - Found BibTeX data source '/Users/removed/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/local/mylibrary.bib'
[583] UCollate.pm:65> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[583] UCollate.pm:65> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[583] Biber.pm:3027> INFO - Sorting list 'nyt/global' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nyt' and locale 'en-US'
[583] Biber.pm:3031> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
[585] bbl.pm:519> INFO - Writing '/Users/removed/Dropbox/Thesis/currentdraft/temptexfiles/test.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[585] bbl.pm:615> INFO - Output to /Users/removed/Dropbox/Thesis/currentdraft/temptexfiles/test.bbl
```

I can see many Unicode characters, just not ğ. Why?

I'm on OSX El Capitan. All TeX related things are updated via TeXLive.

Comment: You should do `\usepackage{fontspec}` rather than loading `fontenc` and `inputenc`, with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Excellent! Can you put it as an answer? Actually @David Carlisle posted an expanded version, so if you don't mind I'll accept his answer? If you do, then please post yours and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `fontenc` with XeLaTeX is wrong, because the engine uses Unicode which is based on Latin-1 for the lowest block and T1 doesn't coincide with Latin-1.

The glyph `ğ` is covered by T1, but it is in a position that can't correspond to the glyph as XeTeX sees it, because it is not in Latin-1.
Other glyphs have the same problem; others that are in Latin-1 are in different positions in T1.

Either use `pdflatex` or load `fontspec` instead of `fontenc`. Note that `inputenc` will do nothing, but it's better to remove it, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[<options>]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{mylibrary.bib}
```

is the correct preamble (add the rest). Note that `\addbibresource` is recommended over `\bibliography` (the `.bib` extension is required with the recommended command).

Comment: ğ works fine for me with pdflatex/T1-encoding.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes but inputenc in utf8 will construct `\u{g}`  from ğ  which will then use the `\accent` primitive over a `g`, with xetex that's all disabled and Unicode goes straight through so you need a font with that slot

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: No ğ is a real glyph in T1 `\DeclareTextComposite{\u}{T1}{g}{167}` (and I know why it doesn't work with xelatex -- after I'm constanly telling people not to use T1-encoded fonts with the unicode engines,)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer With `pdflatex` it's two byte; but for XeTeX it's a single entity.

Comment: For xetex the glyph is at position 287 of the current font  and there is nothing there with a T1 font.

Answer (score 5):

Do not use fontenc with xetex, you are specifying T1 encoded fonts which is a non-unicode encoding with just 256 characters, biber and xetex want unicode so you get in the log

```
 Missing character: There is no ğ in font ecrm1200!
```

ğ  is U+011f so can not be in a T1 encoded font that only has slots up to FF

Instead use

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

and delete

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Unicode in references
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Unicode in references
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I just saw @egreg's response, so out of courtesy I'll accept his answer (if he posts within the next 10 minutes or so). Otherwise, I'll go with yours! :)

Comment: @econ egreg has _far_ too much rep already, vote for me!! :-)

Comment: haha, you're not that far behind! 8 mln people reached... Wow, you guys are cool! :) I'll vote for your answer anyway (just starting so my votes are not registering yet...)