# Non-Latin characters disappear compiling in XeLaTex, but not in PDFLaTeX using Typeface

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, xetex

Recently, I asked a question about typesetting a document using a certain set of fonts [Amstext (chemmacros) causes problems in selecting math fonts in chemfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670326/amstext-chemmacros-causes-problems-in-selecting-math-fonts-in-chemfig) and [Typeface returns fatal coding errors after update of LaTeX core](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670321/typeface-returns-fatal-coding-errors-after-update-of-latex-core)). In the discussion and answers to those questions switching from compiling using PDFLaTeX to using XeLaTeX was proposed. That did work rather well fontwise, yet it introduced another issue: using XeLaTeX non-Latin characters are not printed, but are flawlessly printed compiling with PDFLaTeX.

In the provided MWE you can see a few entries with Turkish or Serbian surnames. These names aren't  correctly printed in both textual citations nor in the bibliography compiling with XeLaTeX. As said, PDFLaTeX compiles correctly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

%----- lettertypen -----
\let\MakeUppercasesaved\MakeUppercase
\def\MakeUppercase#1{\expanded{\uppercase{#1}}}

\usepackage[
    typeface=gfsartemisia:euler,
    sanstypeface=tgheros:scale:0.92,
    mathtypeface=mathdesign:charter,
    textcomp=dontload,
    inputencoding=dontload,
    ]{typeface}
\let\MakeUppercase\MakeUppercasesaved

%----- opmaak pakketten -----
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

%----- layout pakketten -----
\usepackage[body={17.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,0,139} % Color of the article title and sections (navy blue)
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{255,255,120} % Color of the boxes behind the abstract and headings (dark yellow)
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{180,0,0} % Color of the headings of the parts (redbrown)
\definecolor{color4}{RGB}{0,139,0} % Color of chemical notations (dark green)
\definecolor{color5}{RGB}{139,0,139} %Color of captions (dark purple)

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\hypersetup{hidelinks,colorlinks,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=color4,citecolor=color1,linkcolor=color1,bookmarksopen=false,pdfdisplaydoctitle=true}


%===== Referenties =====
%----- bibliografie -----
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,casechanger=auto,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%----- Bronvermelding -----
\addbibresource{files/\jobname.bib}
\urlstyle{rm}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{files/\jobname.bib}
    @article{zeybek2020,
        title = {Analysis of pre-service teachers' learning styles according to {{V}}ermunt learning style model},
        author = {Zeybek, Gülçin and Şentürk, Cihad},
        date = {2020},
        journaltitle = {International Online Journal of Education and Teaching},
        volume = {7},
        number = {2},
        pages = {669--682},
        url = {https://iojet.org/index.php/IOJET/article/view/766},
        urldate = {2022-11-14},
    }
    @article{vermunt2004,
        title = {Patterns in Student Learning: {{Relationships}} between Learning Strategies, Conceptions of Learning, and Learning Orientations},
        shorttitle = {Patterns in Student Learning},
        author = {Vermunt, Jan D. and Vermetten, Yvonne J.},
        date = {2004},
        journaltitle = {Educational Psychology Review},
        volume = {16},
        number = {4},
        pages = {359--384},
        doi = {10.1007/s10648-004-0005-y},
    }
    @incollection{vanwaes2010,
        title = {Fostering {{Students}}' {{Learning}} with {{Study Guides}}: {{The Relationship}} with {{Students}}’ {{Perception}} and {{Learning Patterns}}},
        booktitle = {Facilitating Effective Student Learning through Teacher Research and Innovation},
        author = {Van Waes, Sara and Vanthournout, Gert and Gijbles, David and Donche, Vincent},
        editor = {Valenčič Zuljan, Milena and Vogrinc, Janez},
        date = {2010},
        pages = {49--76},
        publisher = {{Faculty  of Education, University of Ljubljana, Slovenia}},
        location = {{Ljubljana, Slovenia}},
        isbn = {978-961-253-051-8},
        langid = {english}
    }
\end{filecontents}
%===== =====

\begin{document}
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \lipsum[1][1-2] \parencite{zeybek2020}
    
    \textcite[pg. 670]{zeybek2020} \lipsum[3][4]
    
    \citeauthor{vermunt2004, zeybek2020} refer to \parencite{vanwaes2010} \lipsum[2][6] \citetitle[from][pg. 67]{vanwaes2010}
    
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[title=References] 


\end{document}
```

The code contains the solution to the Typeface problem and *Too many math fonts ..* issue asked in the aforementioned questions.

The XeLaTeX output looks like this:
[image]

The PDFLaTeX output gives:
[image]

Compare the first and last citations in both examples. This issue resembles the question asked in [Only one specific character missing when compiling with biber and xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311854/only-one-specific-character-missing-when-compiling-with-biber-and-xelatex), but the answer given there doesn't work here.

**Note** (from comments below): replacing the `typeface` font selection with just `\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}` compiles correctly in both engines. But when the `mathdesign` font packages are loaded as well, the compiling error returns.

Comment: the typeface package is imho not suited for a current xelatex, it doesn't support the TU encoding. Use the fontspec package to setup the fonts.

Comment: why are you using `typeface` at all? It is very old and its own documentation says `%  1. This package is most suited to pdfLaTeX, and not particularly to other TeX formats` ... `If using XeTeX, the fontspec package would make far and away the better choice`

Comment: All true. I was looking to circumvent the PDFLatex restrictions on math fonts and maybe be able to drop `typeface` until it had been updated. Tried `fontspec`, but that didn't solve anything.

Comment: Guess I am to use the older PDFLaTeX compiler and the quick solution to `typeface` you so kindly provided @David Carlisle  after all then. At least I know that my other large documents can be complied with that fix.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer - are you familiar with the packages `fontsetup`  and `mathspec` ? The latter loads `fontspec` and enables to specifically load selected math fonts as addition to the font selections in `fontspec`. Going to tinker and try and see how this works (looks rather elaborate at first sight).

Comment: I wouldn't use mathspec, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487319/2388 why.

Comment: `unicode-math` package is designed for  Unicode-aware engines like xelatex and lualatex. Likewise `fontspec`.

Comment: `Biblatex` can use the `langid=` field of a bibentry and then use `babel`/`polyglossia`'s font setting for that language (using `fontspec` behind the scenes for the Unicode fonts). In general, use Unicode-aware tools for non-ASCII text, not pdflatex and legacy fonts.

Answer (score 1):

The comments to my question let to some trial-by-error experimenting and searching the community for options and solutions. Currently, I am migrating from using PDFLaTeX as compiler to XeLaTeX. I also extensively use the `chemmacros` and its related packages plus `chemfig` to create chemistry exams, additional texts and such to educate my students in the abstract art of chemistry. In that I encountered some reading difficulties of chemical formulas by several students, especially when confronted by a molecular bruto formula (giving its elemental composition) and the accompanying structural formula of that compound. That let to the use of a set of fonts, that I found diminished these reading difficulties.

In PDFLaTeX I can use the `typeface` package together with the patch David Carlisle so kindly provided. The above MWE shows how it can be used to manage the occurrence of the infamous *Too many math fonts ...* issue.

In switching to the modern compiler XeLaTeX another approach is needed. Ulrike Fisher pointed me the way to this solution:

```
%----- lettertypen -----
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\usepackage[sans-style=upright]{unicode-math} % automatically loads fontspec package
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}

\setmainfont{GFS Artemisia}[Scale=1.05]
\setsansfont{FiraSans}[
        Extension = .otf,
        UprightFont = *-Regular,
        ItalicFont = *-Italic,
        BoldFont = *-Medium,
        BoldItalicFont = *-MediumItalic]
```

This replacement of the `typeface` section in the above MWE solves the issues about disappearing characters. (I guess I used the `fontspec` options incorrectly at first.)

With regard to the chemistry: `TeX Gyre Heros` has a *straight* lowercase l that is difficult to distinguish from an uppercase I. `Fira Sans` has a lowercase l that is slightly hooked making reading a compound like AlI3 far better readable even though `Fira Sans` uses more condensed capitals.